# ValueError: empty range for randrange() (100000, 10000, -90000)

Tags: python-3.x, random

The first number is bigger than the second...

```
x = random.randint(100000, 9999)
```

```
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (100000, 10000, -90000)
```

Comment: @SamMason Void. See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the two values around, smallest first

```
x = random.randint(9999, 100000)
```